# Install an Access database with a .NET windows application on a remote computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

I have developed a Desktop Application using Visual Studio 2010 in C# and I am using an Access database file (.accdb) as my backend. The application runs smoothly at my end but when I mail it to my client, the application shows errors everytime it tries to write to the database. I have mailed te database file with the application and the Copy to Output Directory property is set to "Copy if Newer". I am sure the issue is a small one and has something to do with the connectivity or the permissioning of the database file. I need some quick help because I am running out of time. Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think you mean `jet` or `ace`, not `ms-access-2007`.

Comment: No I mean MS-Access 2007

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and/ or call stack?

Comment: Did find you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

What error is the client getting? Maybe s/he doesn't have write permission to their c:\program files directory.

Comment: The client gets the error "Input string is not in the correct format" and also "Operation must be an updatable query". Both these errors come on the insert query. The same query runs smoothly at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Does your client have MS-Access or the ACCDB drivers correctly installed? Seems to be a driver issue to me. What is the connection string you are using to open the connection to the access database?

You may also try converting your database to MDB instead of ACCDB. MDB is more widely used, and its drivers are usually pre-installed on all Windows machines. Also, this format doesn't need MS-Access to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is not obvious by your error messages `Input string is not in the correct format` and `Operation must be an updatable query`, they may indicate that you are using **reserved keywords** as table or column names.

Have a look at [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (MSDN) and check if you have used any of them in your database.